# Switch statement unusual behaviour

Tags: php

`echo get_option('bp-username-field');` and echo `get_option('bp-email-field');` respectively outputs `checked` and `0`. but with this code both the cases are running. i.e. both hello from username and hello from email are dispayed.

```
switch("checked")
{
   case  get_option('bp-username-field'):
                echo 'hello from username';

   case  get_option('bp-email-field'):

                echo 'hello from email';
           ...

}
```

And if i change   `switch("0")` it only echoes hello from email. Also, with `swith(0)` both case are running. What is this behaviour?

Comment: because `0 == 'string'` is `true`

Comment: I suggest you [read the `switch` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a `break` after the case. If not all cases will be executed. That is normal behavior for `switch` Statements

```
switch("checked")
{
   case  get_option('bp-username-field'):
                echo 'hello from username';
                break;
   case  get_option('bp-email-field'):

                echo 'hello from email';
           ...

}
```

Comment: I need to execute all cases. i want to echo for all cases that displays checked.

Comment: @Steve Looks like you need `if` statements not `Switch`. But i think i do not understand your requirements completly. If you do not use `break`, from the first "matching" `case` all other cuted. The following `case` Statements will not be evaluated.

Comment: @jems ok, i think i require several if statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing `break`

```
switch("checked")
{
   case  get_option('bp-username-field'):
                echo 'hello from username';
                break;

   case  get_option('bp-email-field'):

                echo 'hello from email';
                break;
           ...

}
```

---

When the first case gets executed, then you need to break the switch. You need to introduce `break` to break execution of rest of the cases that follows the selected case.

When `switch(0)` was called, it is the final case (as of here), so it doesn't execute the one before the second case.

Comment: but i need to execute all cases and echo hello if the case displays  checked.

Comment: Can you expand your requirement?

Comment: i need to echo if case equals to checked.

Answer (score 1):

switch/case does loose comparison. That's mean that `"checked" == 0` is `true`. What you want to do is:

```
switch(true)
{
   case  get_option('bp-username-field') === "checked":
                echo 'hello from username';

   case  get_option('bp-email-field') === "checked":

                echo 'hello from email';
           ...
}
```

But in a switch statement, the condition is evaluated only once and the result is compared to each case statement. This mean that after the first `case` is evaluate as `true`, all the other `case` will be executed until the end of the switch. What you really want it:

```
if (get_option('bp-username-field') === "checked") {
    echo 'hello from username';
}

if (get_option('bp-email-field') === "checked") {
    echo 'hello from email';
}
```

Comment: it is still displaying hello from email even if get_option('bp-email-field') is not checked.

Answer (score -1):

Because your statement is wrong;
you should compare the variable what ever it is inside switch(variable) to all those cases. for example.

```
$favcolor = "red";

switch ($favcolor) {
    case "red":
        echo "Your favorite color is red!";
        break;
    case "blue":
        echo "Your favorite color is blue!";
        break;
    case "green":
        echo "Your favorite color is green!";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, nor green!";
}
```

Comment: you can do `switch('someconstant') { case $somevariable`, it's not wrong.